# Terminal window has a weird description

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

[image]

Hello,
as you can see my terminal window description is really weird. 2 days ago my terminal was still called "*myname*@LauentiusMacbook" or something. Do you guys know how to fix this or/ and what causes this issue? I'm using zsh and OMZ but i hardly think that that is the issue.

If it helps, this is what my computername and local hostname is.

```
sudo scutil --get ComputerName   
sudo scutil --get LocalHostName
sudo scutil --get HostName
```

[image]

Comment: When showing Terminal output, please copy/paste both the commands run and the result **as text** and add this to the question.

Comment: There was no command, this is how the Terminal Window is called like the moment i open the terminal.

Comment: How do you get to "this is what my computername and local hostname is"?

Comment: Anyway, please check the solutions to the question linked now at the top of your post.

Comment: @nohillside wrong solution. I don't develop remotely or for any other device. This post is strictly talking about the terminal window description since it seems like the rest is alright. Following the solution just changes the hostname, which i tried, but it doesnt make my problem go away

Comment: So when you run `sudo scutil --set HostName "better"` and open a new Terminal tab, it doesn't change a thing?

Comment: Opening a new terminal tab seems to work. Restarted my mac and it seems to finally save the setting, even after quitting the terminal. Thanks